# Styled Component props missing in VS Code with React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code, styled-components

I created a new project and installed all the dependencies to use styled components but for some reason only 4 props are shown when pressing ctrl + space regardless of type. I'm using Typescript and React Native with expo.

Here's an image of the issue:

[image]

If i try to use ReactJS styled components it works but not React Native, any idea what might be causing this?

**Edit 1:**

I was able to "fix" it by manually adding types for styled-components since i had another older project with styled components and typescript. But still, even if i install them manually with yarn the problem persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fixed it by adding this to package.json:

```
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "17.0.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.2"
  }
```